# How to web crawl a DeepZoom image from IIPImage server?

Tags: web-crawler, deepzoom, iipimage

How to get all tiles and metadata of a DeepZoom image hosted on an IIPImage server?

IIPImage suports the IIP protocol (not well documented), MS DeepZoom, and Zoomify

Comment: +1: Fascinated if this is possible. Never thought about web-scraping a  DeepZoom site before. I hope you have plenty of bandwidth and storage available :)

Comment: have a look at the following image: http://merovingio.c2rmf.cnrs.fr/fcgi-bin/iipsrv.fcgi?FIF=PIA03883.pyr.tif&SDS=0,90&JTL=4,80, the last parameter is the crop/zoom. Find the pattern and you can download the whole image. I don't have the time to try it out myself but it can be done

Comment: There's [dezoomify](https://github.com/lovasoa/dezoomify) which scrapes tiles in Zoomify format and stitches them together. Otherwise you can look at the source code of any large image viewer (e.g. [IIPMooViewer](https://github.com/ruven/iipmooviewer)) and reverse engineer it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment so far. Here is an example of an IPPImage generated image that I'd like to scrap: http://archives.aisne.fr/ark:/63271/vta539aaa43cf13b/daogrp/0/layout:table/idsearch:RECH_5fffdec80387d547b467549394099a2c#id:1477809664?center=1644.2339963023235,-1106.9094306240984